# Неправильный ответ в тесте

Tags: python

Как вы думаете, с чем может быть связана ошибка?

> Wrong answer in test #1 There should be two lines with "milk", found:
> 1
>
> Неправильный ответ в тесте № 1 Должны быть найдены две строки с «молоком»:
> 1

Ошибку выдает не сам Python, а сайт, на котором размещено задание.

**Есть задание, цитирую:**

> Давайте смоделируем настоящую кофемашину. Она имеет ограниченный запас
> воды, молока и кофейных зерен, а также одноразовых стаканчиков. Кроме
> того, она подсчитывает, сколько денег получает за продажу кофе.
> Продаем кофе 3 видов: эспрессо, латте и капучино. Конечно, каждый тип
> требует различного количества расходных материалов, за исключением
> того, что все они требуют только одну одноразовую чашку. Во-вторых,
> кофемашина должна пополняться специальным работником. В-третьих,
> работник может быть в состоянии взять деньги из кофемашины.
>
> Возможные действия: «купить кофе», «пополнить», «забрать деньги». Если
> вы хотите купить кофе, введите «купить кофе». Чтобы пополнить все
> расходные материалы для кофемашины, ввести «пополнить». Если вы пьете
> напиток из кофемашины, введите его.
>
> Если пользователь пишет «купить», он может выбрать: эспрессо, латте
> или капучино.
>
> - Для приготовления эспрессо необходимо 250 мл воды и 16 г кофейных зерен, стоит $ 4.
> - Для латте кофеварке нужно 350 мл воды, 75 мл молока и 20 г кофейных зерен. Это стоит $ 7.
> - А для капучино нужно 200 мл воды, 100 мл молока и 12 г кофе. Это стоит $ 6.
>
> Если пользователь пишет «забрать деньги», кофемашина "отдает" все
> деньги.
>
> На данный момент кофемашина имеет 550 долларов, 1200 мл воды, 540 мл
> молока, 120 г кофейных зерен и 9 одноразовых стаканчиков.
>
> Напишите программу, которая печатает состояние кофемашины,
> обрабатывает один запрос от пользователя, а также печатает состояние
> кофемашины после этого. Попробуйте использовать функции для реализации
> каждого действия, которое может сделать кофемашина.

**Вот мой код к задаче:**

```
# machine_has
water = 1200
milk = 540
beans = 120
cups = 9
money = 550
    

# espresso
water_for_one_cup_espresso = 250
beans_for_one_cup_espresso = 16
price_for_one_cup_espresso = 4


# latte
water_for_one_cup_latte = 350
beans_for_one_cup_latte = 20
milk_for_one_cup_latte = 75
price_for_one_cup_latte = 7


# cappuccino
water_for_one_cup_cappuccino = 200
beans_for_one_cup_cappuccino = 12
milk_for_one_cup_cappuccino = 100
price_for_one_cup_cappuccino = 6
    

def buy():
    choice = int(input("What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte, 3 - cappuccino: 3 "))
    if choice == 1:
        print("The coffee machine has: ")
        print("%d of water" % (water - water_for_one_cup_espresso))
        print("%d of milk" % milk)
        print("%d of coffee beans" % (beans - beans_for_one_cup_espresso))
        print("%d of disposable cups" % (cups - 1))
        print("%d of money" % (money + price_for_one_cup_espresso))

    elif choice == 2:
        print("The coffee machine has: ")
        print("%d of water" % (water - water_for_one_cup_latte))
        print("%d of milk" % (milk - milk_for_one_cup_latte))
        print("%d of coffee beans" % (beans - beans_for_one_cup_latte))
        print("%d of disposable cups" % (cups - 1))
        print("%d of money" % (money + price_for_one_cup_latte))
    
    elif choice == 3:
        print("The coffee machine has: ")
        print("%d of water" % (water - water_for_one_cup_cappuccino))
        print("%d of milk" % (milk - milk_for_one_cup_cappuccino))
        print("%d of coffee beans" % (beans - beans_for_one_cup_cappuccino))
        print("%d of disposable cups" % (cups - 1))
        print("%d of money" % (money + price_for_one_cup_cappuccino))
        

def fill():
    water_to_fill = int(input("Write how many ml of water do you want to add: "))
    milk_to_fill = int(input("Write how many ml of milk do you want to add: "))
    beans_to_fill = int(input("Write how many grams of coffee beans do you want to add: "))
    cups_to_fill = int(input("Write how many disposable cups of coffee do you want to add: "))

    print("The coffee machine has:")
    print("%d of water" % (water + water_to_fill))
    print("%d of milk" % (milk + milk_to_fill))
    print("%d of coffee beans" % (beans + beans_to_fill))
    print("%d of disposable cups" % (cups + cups_to_fill))
    print("%d of money" % money)


def take():
    print("I gave you %d$" % money)
    print()
    print("The coffee machine has:")
    print("%d of water" % water)
    print("%d of milk" % milk)
    print("%d of coffee beans" % beans)
    print("%d of disposable cups" % cups)
    print("%d of money" % (money - money))


action = input("Write action (buy, fill, take): ")
if action == "buy":
    buy()
elif action == "fill":
    fill()
elif action == "take":
    take()
```

Comment: Переведите вопрос в целом и задание в частности на русский язык или опубликуйте вопрос на английском stackoverflow

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @Kromster не понял, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас в задании написано, что машина должна выдавать своё состояние, обрабатывать запрос пользователя и снова выдавать своё состояние.

Соответственно, сделаем функцию `state()` и будем запускать её перед и после отработки команды. При этом функции самих команд - упростились.

Ещё пару моментов: убрал лишнюю тройку при запросе вида кофе и переставил знак доллара перед числом.

```
# machine_has
water = 1200
milk = 540
beans = 120
cups = 9
money = 550


# espresso
water_for_one_cup_espresso = 250
beans_for_one_cup_espresso = 16
price_for_one_cup_espresso = 4


# latte
water_for_one_cup_latte = 350
beans_for_one_cup_latte = 20
milk_for_one_cup_latte = 75
price_for_one_cup_latte = 7


# cappuccino
water_for_one_cup_cappuccino = 200
beans_for_one_cup_cappuccino = 12
milk_for_one_cup_cappuccino = 100
price_for_one_cup_cappuccino = 6


def buy():
    global water, milk, beans, cups, money

    choice = int(input("What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte, 3 - cappuccino: "))
    if choice == 1:
        water -= water_for_one_cup_espresso
        beans -= beans_for_one_cup_espresso
        cups -= 1
        money += price_for_one_cup_espresso
        print("Served espresso")

    elif choice == 2:
        water -= water_for_one_cup_latte
        milk -= milk_for_one_cup_latte
        beans -= beans_for_one_cup_latte
        cups -= 1
        money += price_for_one_cup_latte
        print("Served latte")

    elif choice == 3:
        water -= water_for_one_cup_cappuccino
        milk -= milk_for_one_cup_cappuccino
        beans -= beans_for_one_cup_cappuccino
        cups -= 1
        money += price_for_one_cup_cappuccino
        print("Served cappuccino")

def fill():
    global water, milk, beans, cups, money

    water_to_fill = int(input("Write how many ml of water do you want to add: "))
    milk_to_fill = int(input("Write how many ml of milk do you want to add: "))
    beans_to_fill = int(input("Write how many grams of coffee beans do you want to add: "))
    cups_to_fill = int(input("Write how many disposable cups of coffee do you want to add: "))

    water += water_to_fill
    milk += milk_to_fill
    beans += beans_to_fill
    cups += cups_to_fill

def take():
    global water, milk, beans, cups, money

    print("I gave you $%d" % money)
    print()
    money = 0

def state():
    print("The coffee machine has:")
    print("%d of water" % water)
    print("%d of milk" % milk)
    print("%d of coffee beans" % beans)
    print("%d of disposable cups" % cups)
    print("%d of money" % money)

state()
action = input("Write action (buy, fill, take): ")
if action == "buy":
    buy()
elif action == "fill":
    fill()
elif action == "take":
    take()
state()
```